# Where is the python.el documentation?

Tags: python, documentation, ipython

I am using emacs-24.3, which comes with python.el and IPython support out of the box (or so they say).

Is there documentation for this mode? Where can I find it?

Comment: If the question is about doc for a mode, consult the doc string of the mode function (e.g., `python-mode` or whatever). If that doc is incomplete, consider letting the library author/maintainer know (file an enhancement/bug report). While consulting the `Commentary` of the source file can help for things like installing or configuring, users should get help on the mode itself by `C-h f` for the mode function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can visit the file `python.el.gz` which defines the mode doing <kbd>M-x</kbd>`find-library`<kbd>RET</kbd>`python`<kbd>RET</kbd>. The commentary at the beginning of the file is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: +1 for explaining how Emacs can help to figure out how to figure it out.

Comment: Note that it's common for libraries to have detailed commentaries, so `find-library` should be a standard tool when you're looking for documentation.